# VBA to only keep cell value before space

Tags: vba, excel

It seemed like a simple code but I couldn't find it anywhere on the net & I don't know how to write it.

What I want to do is that, say, cell range A1 has a value of "Hey ho he ha".
What I want the code to do is to remove away the rest of the word after the 1st space, so what's left will be with only "Hey".

Thanks!

Comment: I dont know anything about vba but I think this could help http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: The function returns all the values, just split up. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One line Code...

`Range("A1").Value = Split(Range("A1").Value, " ")(0)`

Another one line code (based on IolandaAB's answer)

`If InStr(1, Range("A1").Value, " ") Then Range("A1").Value = Mid(Range("A1").Value, 1, InStr(1, Range("A1").Value, " ") - 1)`

And yet another one line code

`If InStr(1, Range("A1").Value, " ") Then Range("A1").Value = Left(Range("A1").Value, InStr(1, Range("A1").Value, " ") - 1)`

Take your pick :) My favorite is still the first one.

Comment: You don't even need that If condition. You can simply do `Range("A1").Value = Split(Range("A1").Value, " ")(0)` ;)

Comment: Yes pradeep. You are right. That is what Ron Suggested

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub extract()

Dim myString As String, lung As Integer, i As Integer, pos As Integer
myString = Range("A1").value
lung = Len(myString)

For i = 1 To lung
    pos = InStr(i, myString, " ")
    If pos <> 0 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
Range("A1").value = Mid(myString, 1, pos)

End Sub
```

Loop through the value from your cell and exit when the first space is found in your text. Extract the  text before the found space and copy this in your cell.